# How to properly display a three-tiered data structure in iOS using a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitableview

I have the following data-structure:

```
Recipe -> Ingredient Category -> Ingredient
```

I am building a Shopping List view that needs to display each ingredient:

> Recipe
>
> > Ingredient Category
> >
> > > Ingredient
> > >
> > > Ingredient
> >
> > Ingredient Category
> >
> > > Ingredient
> > >
> > > Ingredient
>
> Recipe
>
> > Ingredient Category
> >
> > > Ingredient
> > >
> > > Ingredient
> >
> > Ingredient Category
> >
> > > Ingredient
> > >
> > > Ingredient

If the data structure was simply `Recipe -> Ingredient`, I would simply use a Grouped UITableView style.

But since I have a third tier in the data structure, I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

Can anyone provide any possible solutions?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableViewStyleGrouped` and always make the first row in a section/the Category row a different look by providing a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. You might for instance color it black...

Alternatively, you could show a [detail label](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW30) on each Ingredient, showing its Category.

Comment: So, I had also tried that, but the problem I ran into was when viewForHeaderInSection was called, I was unable to determine if current section was the first Category for a given recipe or not. Also adding to the difficulty was the fact that viewForHeaderInSection seems to be called multiple times for each given section and it was not always in order. I began to think the problem lied in my backing Data Source, which was an Array of Categories, which each have a single Recipe and multiple Ingredients properties - maybe that's not the best approach. I will try to use the Detail Label.